# "An error occurred while signing: Key not valid for use in specified state" when compiling Outlook 2010 add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, signing

I'm building an Outlook 2010 add-in that will tie into our ticketing system using the ticket systems' API.  A week ago I was able to compile and get context/ribbon menus which executed their functions properly.  This morning I added some functions to encrypt and decrypt the API key, but now when I try to compile I get

"Error  1   An error occurred while signing: Key not valid for use in specified state."

There is no line number or file associated with the error.  At first I thought it was something with the System.Security class I had included, but commenting out everything associated with that and removing the reference to System.Security did not fix the problem.

I have tried restarting everything and doing a clean build with no luck.  On the advise of [this forum post](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/general-discussions/key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state.aspx) I have tried deleting both my machine and local RSA files but that made no difference.  I have also tried deleting the _TemporaryKey.pfx file in my solution in the hopes that if that were having issues that VS would recreate a new working one, but that didn't even change the error message to tell me the file was missing.

After all this I tried opening a different add-in project that I hadn't modified for about a week and it too had the same error.  I'm not sure at this point if it is a problem with Visual Studio or my computer but a brand new Outlook add-in project will compile successfully so it is only affecting old projects.

Comment: microsoft and their specific error messages ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creating a new test certificate seems to have solved the problem.  [This blog post](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/an-error-occurred-while-signing-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state/) pointed me in the right direction.

- Open the properties page for the project that is giving the error.
- Click the Signing tab.
- Click Create Test Certificate.
- Enter a password and click OK.

This got things working again for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same error after I had reloaded my machine.  As Nick mentions, you can create a new cert and go from there.

What I ended up doing instead was adding the original certificate back into my certificate store so that it could be used again during the Visual Studio publish process. Double clicking on the PFX file and following the prompts should get you there.

One thing to note is that if enough time has gone by the certificate might expire and it would be best to create a new one.